# Angular gives same generic error

Tags: angularjs

When I try to run angular code , it always gives this generic error message though it is nor problem with module api or name. For example, in this case, I put name value pairs separated in object with semi colon in config method. After changing to comma, it is fine now. But it does not tell exact cause is in config not in module name. How do I find exact cause?

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Comment: post your code to see the issue

Comment: @chinni did my answer helped you solved your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a common error. It occurs when the `ng-app` name declared in your template differs from the one used in your script, for example :

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('myApp') // <-- ERROR OCCURS HERE, it should be 'app'
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

// controller code here

}]);
```